# Are these center caps on Audi wheels exchangable?

Tags: wheels, audi

I got `4F0 601 025 N` wheels on my '02 Passat. They fit well, but what is bothering me is, that there is only one center cap left. Its number is `4F0 601 165`. I haven't found good deal on it anywhere, but there are a lot of cheap `8E0 601 165`'s. Are they exchangeable? Thanks everyone!

Wheels looks like this:
[image: WHeels]

Comment: Is there anyway you can link their dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

No, these will not fit. the latter ones are 3.3 inch in diameter, and the prior ones are 2.8 inch. Besides the first ones use lug nut cusps, and the second ones do not possess those, they are just mere caps.

Comment: For 35 dollars its better you get these 4 peices: https://www.amazon.com/4pcs-AUDI-WHEEL-CENTER-BLACK/dp/B00RG4Y27U/ref=sr_1_1?s=automotive&ie=UTF8&qid=1496524213&sr=1-1&keywords=4F0+601+025+N

Comment: Thanks for the link, but those are `4F0 601 165 N` - mind the N at the end and they are sadly completely different... Both caps look very similar to this: https://www.amazon.com/Hubcap-Wheel-Center-8E0601165-pieces/dp/B0082CTSOM

Comment: Send me the links to the caps you have found. I'll check the specs for a fit.

Comment: Basically, all I found was either `SRA` version - same dimensions, slightly different colour: http://www.ebay.com/itm/Genuine-Wheel-Center-Hub-Caps-4x-SET-Gray-Metallic-AUDI-A3-S3-A4-B7-A6-C6-04-08/191756250911 and a version without a logo: http://www.ebay.de/itm/1213-4-Nabenkappen-Nabendeckel-Felgendeckel-149-142-mm-4F0601165-8P0601025AA-/311824329403?hash=item489a2daabb:g:nxgAAOSw5VFWLJ6n then I found tons of used ones, where was nothing apart from model number. Thank you!

Comment: Is this your exact rim: http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Audi-16-Inch-Alloy-Wheel-7JX16H2-ET35-5-Stud-4F0-601-025N-/222074971211

Comment: If yes, God willing the amazon linked caps will fit.

Comment: Yes. The ones I linked.

Comment: How are they? Upload some pictures.

Comment: How did they fit?